# QSerialPort - Lectura cortada

Tags: c++, qt

Estoy teniendo inconvenientes para poder leer lineas enteras desde el puerto serie en linux. Tengo un gps que se conecta al puerto serie y no logro que las lineas leìdas de èl lleguen completas. Pongo el còdigo que tengo (tomado del ejemplo Terminal Example de QT. En ese ejemplo, ellos mandan lo que reciben a un QPlainTextEdit, y muestran el QPlainTextEdit entonces les queda "bonita" la salida...pero yo necesito la linea completa para procesarla. Aqui va mi codigo (vale aclarar que el new està hecho en otra parte del codigo):

```
void MainWindow::openSerialPort()
{
    m_serial->setPortName("/dev/ttyUSB0");
    m_serial->setBaudRate(9600);
    connect(m_serial, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &MainWindow::readData);

    if (m_serial->open(QIODevice::Read)) {
        qDebug() << "Conectado Correctamente!";
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Error al conectar!";
    }
}

void MainWindow::readData()
{
    const QByteArray data = m_serial->readAll();
    qDebug() << data << endl;
}
```

Y la salida obtenida es la siguiente:

> Conectado Correctamente!
>   "DAA,-61.262786,-37.245445,587.6,0.1,288.6,40718,20505200,7\r\n00,7\r\nDATA,-61.262786,-37.245445,587.3,0.1,288.6,40718,20505000,7\r\nDATA,-61.262786,-37.245445,587.6,0.1,288.6,40718,20505200,7\r\n"
>
> "St"
>
> "arti"
>
> "ng "
>
> "to p"
>
> "roce"
>
> "ss.."
>
> ".\r\n"
>
> "DAT"
>
> "A,-6"
>
> "1.26"
>
> "2798"
>
> ",-3"
>
> "7.24"
>
> "5452"
>
> ",58"
>
> "7.9,"
>
> "0.5,"
>
> "0.0,"
>
> "4071"
>
> "8,20"
>
> "505"
>
> "700,7\r\n"
>
> "DATA"
>
> ",-61"

Cuando en realidad, yo esperaba obtener lo mismo que la salida de programa ejemplo Terminal que es la mostrada siguientemente:

```
DATA,-61.262786,-37.245445,587.3,0.1,288.6,40718,20505000,7
DATA,-61.262786,-37.245445,587.6,0.1,288.6,40718,20505200,7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que parece que está sucendiendo es que `readData` se invoca en numerosas ocasiones y en cada ocasión contiene únicamente un fragmento de los datos... tendrías que preparar la rutina de lectura para que vaya concatenando las lecturas sucesivas y, después que separe por saltos de línea:

```
void MainWindow::readData()
{
  static QString buffer;

  buffer += m_serial->readAll();

  while( int pos = buffer.indexOf("\r") != -1 )
  {
    qDebug() << buffer.left(pos);
    buffer = buffer.mid(pos+2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

googleando un poco llegué a la siguiente solucion:

```
void MainWindow::readData()
{
    while (m_serial->canReadLine()) 
        qInfo() << m_serial->readLine();
}
```

Con esas simples lineas, tenemos en el buffer la linea completa que llega desde el puerto serie. Por lo que entiendo, el puerto serie seria quien hace el buffering hasta que està la linea completa y recien ahi se puede hacer el readLine. A mi me solucionò un gran problema estas lineas.