# comunicacion serial PIC Qt

Tags: qt, serialport, pic

estoy haciendo una interfaz en QT la cual debe de mostrar valores de
diferentes sensores, utilizo un PIC 18f4580 con comunicación rs232 para la lectura y transmisión de datos, para mandar los datos los coloco en una cadena de caracteres y los envío de la siguiente manera :

```
#use RS232(BAUD=9600,BITS=8,PARITY=N,XMIT=PIN_C6,RCV=PIN_C7)
k[0]='a';
k[1]='1';
k[2]='2';
k[3]='1';
k[4]='2';
k[5]='1';
k[6]='3';
k[7]=' '; 
while(1){
printf("%s",k);
delay_(250);
}
```

Y para recibirlos en Qt configuro el puerto y recibo de la siguiente manera:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
serial = new QSerialPort (this);
serial->setPortName("com3");
serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
connect (serial , & QSerialPort :: readyRead , this , & MainWindow :: read);
void MainWindow::read()
{
if(serial->isReadable()){
QString k=serial->readAll();
ui->label_7->setText(k);
}
```

La idea es que de la cadena comparo el primer valor, lo comparo y asigno el valor a la variable correspondiente, pero empecé primero en mostrar lo que recibía Qt en un *label* pero observe que no recibía siempre la cadena completa
o solo recibía solo una parte o a veces nada. trate de meterlo en un ciclo para que recibiera los 8 elementos de la cadena pero se congelaba y no respondía la aplicación.

intente con `readLine()` y `read(k,8)` para especificar de cuantos elementos iba a ser la cadena pero obtengo lo mismo, incluso mandando los datos cada 2 segundos ocurre lo mismo.

Comment: Me está sucediendo exactamente lo mismo. Comparto el enlace a mi pregunta para ver si entre las respuestas que obtengamos podemos sacar algo en limpio. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177949/qserialport-lectura-cortada

Comment: Si pruebas la conexión desde un terminal de puerto serie... la comunicación es correcta? Si ese programa también falla entonces es probable que la configuración de la conexión no sea correcta o que el emisor tiene errores

Comment: @eferion si lo probe con el programa hércules y si recibe bien la cadena

Comment: Mira a ver si esta otra [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/178069/463) soluciona tu problema

Comment: @eferion me ayudo pero aun tengo problemas  , le indique a Qt que enviara lo que recibiera y en la mayoría de las veces aunque recibiera la cadena completa no la mostraba y otras solo mostraba un carácter y enviaba la cadena sin ese carácter,  siempre era el ultimo

Comment: @eferion como en el otro post le puse al final \r y le indique a Qt que enviara lo que recibiera y recibe completa la cadena pero no la muestra  en la interfaz, muestra pedazos

Answer (score -1):

googleando un poco llegué a la siguiente solucion:

```
void MainWindow::readData()
{
    while (m_serial->canReadLine()) 
        qInfo() << m_serial->readLine();
}
```

Con esas simples lineas, tenemos en el buffer la linea completa que llega desde el puerto serie. Por lo que entiendo, el puerto serie seria quien hace el buffering hasta que està la linea completa y recien ahi se puede hacer el readLine. A mi me solucionò un gran problema estas lineas.

Comment: Hola Emiliano, veo que esta respuesta es un [duplicado exacto de tu otra respuesta en otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177949/qserialport-lectura-cortada/178206#178206). Normalmente cuando una misma respuesta sirve para dos preguntas, eso quiere decir que las preguntas son la misma (y por tanto duplicadas). ¿Dirías que las dos preguntas son iguales? Si sí, marcaría esta como duplicada de la tuya (que se hizo antes). No afectará a tu respuesta, pero servirá para enlazarlas y ayudar a encontrar la solución a usuarios que puedan tener el mismo problema.

Comment: @Emiliano Torres probe lo que dijiste y aun así no me muestra los valores, ya no creo que sea cosa de la comunicación por que le indico que envíe lo que recibe y si envía la cadena completa. tu como muestras los datos que recibes??, en una interfaz?

Comment: @rasenganum, te cuento que en la respuesta que publiquè la estoy mostrando por la consola standard pero en mi sistema la estoy mostrando en un widget y a su vez la estoy parseando para procesarla y la trama me llega correcta.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro entiendo que es la misma pregunta...fueron realizadas con minutos de diferencia por eso quizas no la vi (yo la formulè ultimo)